# Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created a database at php-myadmin and I want to create a connection between database and java, for that I have written this code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


public class B {

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql87928-jahanzeb.j.layershift.co.uk/jahanzeb","root","**********");
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from school");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next())
            System.out.printf("%-5s%-5s%-5s",result.getString(1),result.getString(2),result.getString(3));

    }

}
```

but I am getting an error after running this, please tell how to solve this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at B.main(B.java:12)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Your database server doesn't seem to accept connections from your Java server.

Comment: The `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect` could be occured because of a wrong url.

Comment: check the database server or the url, also check the network(firewall , routine), can try ping the server

Comment: Don't have applications connect to databases as 'root', and don't post your root password here, or anywhwere else either.

Comment: Can you connect from your local machine using the mysql client?